# Curl error 404 when installing apple-gcc42 via Homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rvm, homebrew

I'm following these instructions http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#step-4 to install the tools I need to run Ruby 1.9.3 to develop apps with Rails on OS Mountain Lion.

When running the line

```
brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
```

I get

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Download failed: http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg
```

I tried several times in the past ten hours. Is there an alternative way to install apple-gcc42?

Comment: The problem is linked to this issue: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/15415

Answer (score 1):

The research.att.net server hosting the gcc-42 package is experiencing downtime according to the issue posted by the other user, which is installing another formula that depends on this download. Just give it time.

I start getting this error yesterday around 10 PM GMT -5.

Edit:
The issue is also reported in the apple-gcc42 repo: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/101, it appears the final answer is "wait"

Comment: Issue was closed, the files are back again

Comment: is there a mirror? I hate adding a 'me too' comment but issue has resurfaced. is there a manual way of installing something via brew? like install from /users/aaasdfsadfasdfsadf/blah??

Comment: @cbrulak, the download URL is on the recipe. I'm not an expert on brew, but I guess you could clone that recipe and change the URL to match your mirror. This recipe, originally doesn't considers mirrors and uses the version number to build the URL.

Comment: it started workign about 2 seconds after I left this comment and a few others :) But there also doesn't seem to be a mirror so probably a dead end now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install homebrew/versions/gcc48` according to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers, https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install#ruby and http://www.stok.ca/blog/2014/08/10/building-ruby-1-8-7-p374-on-osx-mavericks-now-homebrew-has-dropped-apple-gcc42/